# if, elif, else chain not working correctly?

Tags: python

I'm working through 'Learn Python the Hard Way' and I've hit a roadblock. The book gives a unit test and asks you to write a function to satisfy the tests. But when I import this function to the interactive shell to test it out, any input returns 'direction' and I can't figure out why.

Here's my code:

```
def pos(item):
    """ Get part of speech for item. """
    pos = ''
    if item == 'north' or 'south' or 'east':
        return 'direction'
    elif item == 'go' or 'kill' or 'eat':
        return 'verb'
    elif item == 'the' or 'in' or 'of':
        return 'stop'
    elif item == 'bear' or 'princess':
        return 'noun'
    else:
        try:
            int(item)
            return 'number'
        except ValueError:
            return 'error'
```

Comment: `bool('south')` evaluates to `True`

Comment: Hmm, I wonder why you are setting ``pos`` to an empty string in the first line. You don't use it anywhere else.

Comment: Ah yeah, that empty string was a leftover from an old code snippet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should have written this:

```
if item == 'north' or item == 'south' or item == 'east':
```

or, alternatively:

```
if item in ('north', 'south', 'east'):
```

The same applies for the remaining branches.

To explain why your original code failed, consider how Python parses the following expression:

```
item == 'north' or 'south' or 'east'
```

What Python does is as follows (note the parentheses which denote the order of parsing):

```
(item == 'north') or 'south' or 'east'
```

You have three sub-expressions here. `item == 'north'` is likely to be false (unless you happened to have entered `'north'`). However, `'south'` or `'east'`, when evaluated in a boolean context (i.e. a condition), is always `True`, so you end up with `(item == 'north') or True or True`, which is of course `True`.

Answer (score 4):

You're using `or` wrong. It should be

```
if item == 'north' or item == 'south' or item == 'east':
```

or, more idiomatically,

```
if item in ('north', 'south', 'east')
```

---

The reason this is coming up wrong is because of the way Python puts the brackets in the expression. You might think it's doing

```
if item == ('north' or 'south' or 'east')
```

but what's actually happening is

```
if (item == 'north') or ('south') or ('east')
```

and `'south'`, being a non-empty string, is always `True`. (Although, the former wouldn't work either, because `'north' or 'south' or 'east'` will be evaluated to `'east'` due to the way Python short-circuits `or`. But that's more complicated and you don't need to worry about it.)

---

Incidentally, you may prefer the following idiom, though yours is just as good.

```
items = {}
items['north'] = items['south'] = items['east'] = 'direction'
items['go'] = items['kill'] = items['eat'] = 'verb'
items['the'] = items['in'] = items['of'] = 'stop'
items['bear'] = items['princess'] = 'noun'

try:
    return items[item]
except KeyError:
    pass

try:
    int(item)
except ValueError:
    pass
else:
    return 'number'

return 'error'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if item == 'north' or 'south' or 'east':
```

determines the truth value of everything between or's. non-empty strings have the True truthvalue, so given the input `'west'`, this evaluate to:

```
if False or True or True:
```

Instead, you want

```
if item == 'north' or item == 'south' or item == 'east':
```

, or, more pythonic:

```
if item in ('north', 'south', 'east'):
```